# not getting the proper Result when the Sql query is executed

Tags: php

I want if the sql query is executed then and give the count means result 1 then it redirect to profile.php otherwise it redirect to candidate.php

```html
<?php include "includes/header.php";?>

<?php
 $email=$_SESSION['email'];

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hr");
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM candidate_registration WHERE resume IS NULL && email='$email'";
  if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)==true){
      header('Location:candidateprofile.php');
  }
else if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)==false){
    header('Location:user\profile.php');
}
```

Comment: You don't actually say what's going wrong, so my first question is why are you running the same query twice just to check if it's true and then if it's false? What's wrong with the `if` and an `else`? Your main issue is that mysqli_query will be true-y if the query is run successfully, whether there are rows or not. Perhaps you meant to make use of [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows).

Comment: Plus, you are not currently basing your decision on any actual _count_ to begin with here. A query that does simply not find any records is _not_ an error, mysqli_query will return true in _both_ cases, because it was able to successfully execute the query without errors. You want to check the number of rows the result set contains instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should look like that

```
SELECT count(*) AS counter FROM candidate_registration WHERE resume IS NULL && email='$email'
```

After that you must check what is the value of your counted records.

Based on your request if it finds at least 1 records it will points it to `profile.php` otherwise to `candidateprofile.php`

```
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_row();

    if($row[0]>0){
     header('Location:user\profile.php');
    }
    else{
      header('Location:candidateprofile.php');
    }
```

Basically you want to **COUNT** your records. The way you are doing it your statement is always true because an empty mysql return is still valid. So checking if the result is `true` will actually always returns true.

*Tip: Your code is open to SQL injection. Read about using prepared statements so you don't run into "unexpected" problems.*